# Optimal threshold for rejecting in classification model

Tags: classification, optimization, confusion-matrix

Let's say I have a model to detect fake product. The model predict the probability whether the product is fake, with 0.0 being authentic, 1.0 is fake. Each true prediction (that product is not fake), I get 1dollar from customer. Each false prediction (that product is not fake, but turns out it is), I pay 50dollars to client. What is the threshold for model cut-off to maximize profit ?

Comment: We need one more piece of information, and one daring assumption. The missing piece of information is how high the prevalence of fakes is - and how this prevalence depends on the predictors you presumably use in your model. The daring assumption is that your model is correct. There is no answer without these two inputs.

Comment: Yes we can assume the model is correct and we can trust the probablity, meaning a 0.4 on fake scale will likely be less fake than a 0.6. Can we make calculation based on some variable X for prelevance of fake ? I suppose this can really be a real life scenario, where you need to quantify the 'cost' of false negative and false positive. How do people do it in real life ?

Comment: Let's define "positive" = "the product is fake". We have the cost of true negatives (the product is not fake, and we treat it as such, cost -1) and of false negatives (the product is fake, but we treat it as non-fake, cost 50). We also need the costs of true positives and false positives. Given that, we can calculate the expected cost as a function of the prevalence and the threshold, find the optimal threshold for each prevalence, and plot.